# Typescript says exported symbol isn't exported

Tags: typescript

I have a simple project

```
$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ocket8888 ocket8888   72 Apr 29 09:30 index.ts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ocket8888 ocket8888  105 Apr 29 09:31 main.ts
drwxrwxr-x 4 ocket8888 ocket8888 4096 Apr 29 09:26 node_modules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ocket8888 ocket8888  206 Apr 29 09:27 package.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ocket8888 ocket8888 1000 Apr 29 09:26 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ocket8888 ocket8888  222 Apr 29 09:33 tsconfig.json
```

In `index.ts` I export a class, and in `main.ts` I import that class.

`index.ts`

```js
export class Testquest {
    constructor(public readonly foo: string) {}
}
```

`main.ts`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { Testquest } from ".";

const a = new Testquest("bar");

console.log(a.foo);
```

When I try to build this, `tsc` says:

```
$ npx tsc
main.ts:2:10 - error TS2459: Module '"."' declares 'Testquest' locally, but it is not exported.

2 import { Testquest } from ".";
           ~~~~~~~~~

  main.ts:2:10
    2 import { Testquest } from ".";
               ~~~~~~~~~
    'Testquest' is declared here.


Found 1 error in main.ts:2
```

As you can see, however, the class is exported. So I don't know why Typescript is so sure it isn't.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "ts-export-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Note that importing from the non-existent file `./index.js` works, but my linter tells me that the `/index.js` portion is a "useless path segment", and I know from experience I should be able to import symbols from a directory if it has an `index.ts` file that exports the symbol - I don't know why that's suddenly not working here.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated: 2021-04-30**

### Solution

#### 1

By providing the file name (may or may not include the extension), TypeScript can resolve the file correct.

`main.ts`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { Testquest } from "./index";

const a = new Testquest("bar");

console.log(a.foo);
```

#### 2

Change `main.ts` to other name.

---

### Reason

Possible reason is that TypeScript resolved "." to "", and which resolved to a directory.

TS will then try to resolve `./main.ts` before `./index.ts`. [TS Handbook: Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-nodejs-resolves-modules)

Which lead to self referencing in your code. i.e.

```
import { Testquest } from "./main";
```

Comment: My built project has no dependency on Typescript, and should be equally valid in any ECMAScript context including a browser.

Comment: Is your compiler using TypeScript?

Comment: My compiler *is* `typescript`.

Answer (score -1):

Change type of module to commonjs in your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`

In `package.json`

change `"type": "commonjs",`

```json
{
  "name": "ts-export-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

in `tsconfig.json`

change `"module": "commonjs",`

remove `"moduleResolution": "node",`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, the same error occurs after those changes.